# CLEAR ROWS ON MULTIPLE SHEETS _ TIME DRIVEN TRIGGERS

Tags: google-apps-script

I run scenarios through integromat but i need to clear rows before the scenarios runs ( everynight)
I figured out that google app script would be a better solution, but i don't know the language.
I found this out that works

```
function clearContentsOnly() {
var range = SpreadsheetApp
           .getActive()
           .getSheetByName("INTEGROMAT1")
           .getRange('A2:D150');
 range.clearContent();
}
```

but i need to apply it to several sheets INTEGROMAT1 INTEGROMAT2 and INTEGROMAT3... tried few things but it's not working

and another question,
i set up the script tu run every night but
".getActive()" doesn't it mean the spreadsheet has to be open when the function is running ? shouldn't i call the spreadsheet by its name if the script runs every night with time driven trigger ?
would be grateful for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the spreadsheet does not need to be open when the function is running.

```
function clearContentsOnly() {
  const ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActive()  // if script is bundled into a spreadsheet
  // const ss =SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL) // if standalone script, or you just want to open another spreadsheet

  const sheets = ["INTEGROMAT1", "INTEGROMAT2"]  // add an array element for each of the sheets you want cleared
  sheets.forEach(sh=>sh.getDataRange().clearContent())
}
```